# I'm recreating a remote host on my local and getting a Routing Error ( No Route Matches )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, iframe, localhost

Essentially I'm recreating an S3 server so that my testing/development suite can work.

A user uploads a file tree, and normally I upload this to s3 and serve its index.html through an iFrame, but for testing purposes I need to perform this locally.

So right now I have it that a user uploads a file tree, and it unpacks it locally under `/public/system/quizzes` .

But when I open an iFrame for this URL, it returns

```
Routing Error 
No route matches [GET] "/quizzes/141/index.html"
```

Is there anyway to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct URL for that would be `/system/quizzes/141/index.html`, because it's within the `system` directory within the `public` directory. If you wanted it without the "system" part, move it out of that directory.

Comment: Thanks so much Ryan! I can't believe I missed that.